# Executable jar won't find the properties files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, maven

I use this code in my program to load a properties file:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
URL url = new App().getClass().getResource(PROPERTIES_FILE);
properties.load(url.openStream());
```

The code runs fine in Eclipse. Then I package the program into a JAR named MyProgram.jar, and run it, I got a NullPointerException at the second line. The JAR doesn't contain the properties file, they both are in the same directory. I am using Maven to create the JAR. How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE: I don't want to add the properties file to the JAR, since it will be created at deployment time.

Comment: Side note: Is there any reason you're using `getResource()` instead of `getResourceAsStream()`, since you're just using it as a stream anyway?

Comment: No, I don't have any particular reason.

Comment: How do you run your jar? If via java -jar, can you try java -cp ./MyProgram.jar <classname> and see if it works?

Comment: @Tomer: that's a workaround, not a solution. Still, it won't work. You aren't taking the root folder of the JAR in the classpath.

Comment: @Hai: Why did you remove the `maven` tag? You commented on my answer "Do you know how to add it via maven?". So you're using maven and since it's doing things differently, the final answer depends on that. I don't know how, so I deleted the answer and retagged the question for better attendance. Maven guys are the only who can reliably answer this question.

Comment: Because I think it's not a Maven problem. I googled and found some similar questions without any solutions. But I'll add back the `maven` tag.

Comment: As far I understand Maven, it's the one who should generate the appropriate `MANIFEST.MF` with the `Class-Path: .` entry for you as outlined in my answer. I only don't know from top of head how to tell Maven to do that :)

Comment: Thanks. Can I update the JAR via command line then?

Comment: is your PROPERTIES_FILE a relative or an absolute argument?

Comment: @BalusC: It was intended as a diagnostic step, not a solution (hence comment and not an answer :-))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

BalusC is right, you need to instruct Maven to generate a `MANIFEST.MF` with the current directory (`.`) in the `Class-Path:` entry.

Assuming you're still using the Maven Assembly Plugin and the `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor to build your executable JAR, you can tell the plugin to do so using the following:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> <!-- HERE IS THE IMPORTANT BIT -->
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: If you're not using the maven assembly plugin, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: With the `executions` section, I don't have to run `mvn assembly:assembly` separately right? By the way, thanks for answering all my questions on Maven.

Comment: @HaiMinhNguyen: Indeed, the above `execution` binds the `single` goal on the `package` phase. As a result, running `mvn package` does create the assembly. Oh, and you're welcome.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach you should take, Hai Minh Nguyen.

Comment: Hello,

I tried using the above method to create a jar-with-depencies that could load a properties file located in the same directory but it does not work. I run my jar using "java -jar myjar.jar".

I tried retrieving the properties file using both Class.getResource() Class.ClassLoader.getResource(), with and without a leading slash in the file name, but none of these work.

If i println the content of java.class.path, I only get my jar file (no ".", though it is correctly set in the MANIFEST's Class-Path).

Could someone help me please?

Comment: This thread was helpful to me. In my case (non-maven project), I also had to make the path of the resource I was requesting (which was buried in my src tree) absolute by prefacing it with a "/" (linux).

Answer (score 18):

There are two **workarounds**:

1. Don't use the JAR as executabele JAR, but as library.

   ```
   java -cp .;filename.jar com.example.YourClassWithMain
   ```
2. Obtain the root location of the JAR file and get the properties file from it.

   ```
   URL root = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
   URL propertiesFile = new URL(root, "filename.properties");
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(propertiesFile.openStream());
   ```

None of both are recommended approaches! The recommend approach is to have the following entry in JAR's `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Class-Path: .
```

Then it'll be available as classpath resource the usual way. You'll really have to instruct Maven somehow to generate the `MANIFEST.MF` file like that.

Comment: Oops I tried the first option before but I used . COMMA filename.jar. Maybe that's why it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's one reason for avoiding the Classpath - namely if the content changes between reads.  The resource loader caches the first content

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this is to respond to your comment:

You need to make sure that the properties file is on the class path with the right root for the java invocation that stars up the jar file. if your path is

stuff/things.properties

and the runtime location is

/opt/myapp/etc/stuff/things.properties

and the jar file is in

/opt/myapp/bin/myjar

then you need to launch as

/path/to/java -cp "/opt/myapp/etc:/opt/myapp/bin/myjar.jar" my.pkg.KavaMain

working with this kind of config can be irksome in a dev environment, luckily, there's the [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) that will get you the right kind of launch scenario.

Original Answer:

You want to read about [the maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html).

Basically you want to add something like this:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <resources>
                        <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                <includes>
                                        <include>**/*properties</include>
                                </includes>
                        </resource>
                </resources>
        </configuration>
<plugin>
```

to your pom.xml assuming that you're propertis file is with your java sources -- really it should be in src/main/resources.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add the properties file to the JAR. It will be changed at deployment time.

Comment: As per your edit: the `-cp` argument is **ignored** when using `-jar` argument. It has really to go in `MANIFEST.MF` file :)

Comment: @BalusC righto, fixed up.  Can't go in the MANIFEST.MF if it could move at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and this thread was a big help!  FYI, I modified my Ant buildfile to do the MANIFEST-making, then designated that manifest when JAR-ing my server-side code:

```
<!-- Create a custom MANIFEST.MF file, setting the classpath. -->
<delete file="${project.base.dir}/resources/MANIFEST.MF" failonerror="false"/>
<manifest file="${project.base.dir}/resources/MANIFEST.MF">
  <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
</manifest>

<!-- JAR the server-side code, using the custom manifest from above. -->
<jar destfile="services/${name}.aar" manifest="${project.base.dir}/resources/MANIFEST.MF">
[....]
```

Answer (score -3):

thanks to all this code work out for me this url get our runnable jar location
so easily i have to read my properties file so put your properties file  in your runnable jar file location

```java
URL root = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
URL propertiesFile = new URL(root, "filename.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(propertiesFile.openStream());
```