# Adding the current directory to a JAR file's classpath

Tags: java, deployment, ant, classpath

My code is being deployed as a JAR file. The JAR contains a directory `lib` which contains a number of third-party JARs which my code requires. I've added these to the `classpath`, using Ant, via the `MANIFEST.MF`.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 20.5-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: com.package.Class
Class-Path: ../lib/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar ../lib/dbunit-2.4.8.jar ../lib/gua
va-10.0.1.jar ../lib/hsqldb.jar ../lib/javax.jms.jar ../lib/log4j-1.2
 .16.jar ../lib/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar ../lib/ojdbc14.jar ../lib/slf4j-
 api-1.6.4.jar ../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar ../lib/xmlunit-1.3.jar
```

There is also a `queries.properties` file which is in the root of the JAR.

There are two further properties files which are required. I would like these to reside in the same directory as the JAR file and for the code to be able to locate them. I believe for the code to be able to locate these properties files, they need to be in the `classpath`. I therefore need to add the JAR file's directory to the `classpath`.

Firstly, is this the correct approach of should I use an alternative means of locating the properties files?

If this is correct, how do I use Ant to add the JAR's current directory to the classpath in `MANIFEST.MF`? I added the JARs in the `lib` directory to the `classpath` using the `manifestclasspath` Ant task.

Comment: *"I would like these to reside in the same directory as the JAR file"*  If I'm the user of the program, I'd prefer them to be 1) In a sub-directory of `user.home` (where they are easily accessible to my back-up script, as opposed to the software, which isn't backed up). Or.. 2) At a location chosen by me (using a file-chooser) at application installation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for you contribution. The application is going to be executed as a scheduled task and does not require any user intervention. It's more a case of keeping the properties files and JAR file together to aid deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `.` as a reference to the current directory?

```
   <jar jarfile="dummy.jar">
            <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.package.Class"/>
                    <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". ${jar.class.path}"/>
            </manifest>               
    </jar>
```

Please also see [Executable jar won't find the properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126030/executable-jar-wont-find-the-properties-files)