# Self-executable jar and external property-files

Tags: java, jar

Suppose i have the following excerpt of a MANIFEST.MF of an executable jar file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.intersportleitner.skischule.gui.window.SkischulApplicationWindow
Class-Path: .
...
```

Shouldn't it be possible to have a directory structure like this:

```
Appdir
  |- bla.jar (self-executable)
  |- x.properties
  |- y.properties
```

Because if i try to load the properties with the following code-fragment i get a IOException: Stream closed in properties.load(stream):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream istream=SkischulApplicationWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("y.properties");
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(istream);
properties.load(stream);
stream.close();
```

The exception is a bit misleading as actually istream is null (remarked that as i tried to call a method of istream for testing purposes...), so the properties-file isn't found and i have no idea why it fails because according to [Executable jar won't find the properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126030/executable-jar-wont-find-the-properties-files) it should work this way...

Comment: Are you using AppDir as execution directory? I mean, are you executing: `java -jar bla.jar` *standing* on that directory?

Answer (score 2):

`getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` are reliant on the class loaders implementation & class path.

I tend to only use this approach when I'm looking for embedded resources, but that's just me

You "could" try

```
InputStream istream=SkischulApplicationWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/y.properties");
```

Instead

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers i also tried if it helps if i add a '/' before the actual filename and it still failed. 

@helios: yes Appdir as in the example is the current working directory and i execute it like this java -jar bla.jar