# Java executable jar classpath confusion

Tags: java, classpath

I have read the answer about executable jars and adding the current path to the classpath [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126030/executable-jar-wont-find-the-properties-files).

I added the plugins to pom.xml, I checked and this line is in fact added to MANIFEST.MF:

```
Class-Path: .
```

Now according to [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax) documentation, it will look in the current classpath for a log4j2.xml file.

My understanding is, that if I place log4j2.xml in the same directory as the jar, and execute the jar while I am in that directory, then it will find the log4j2.xml.

However, it only finds it when I add a

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/file
```

to the java command.

What am I missing?

Frankly, it just seems easier to forget about the classpath stuff and just add a bunch of -D terms to the java command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `.` is evaluated as current directory relative to the `java` process current working directory (when processes are started by the OS, they are given a working directory). You can see the working directory of the JVM that runs your program by examinating the system property `user.dir` from withing your program.

```sh
# current directory is /home/rick
$pwd
/home/rick
# the code archive is not in the current wd
$ls /home/rick/myapps
app.jar
# the conf file is
$ls .
log4j2.xml
# This will work as expected
$java -jar /home/rick/myapps/app.jar
```

Strictly speaking, the JAR doesn't even need to be on your filesystem: for example, it could be downloaded from the network and extracted in memory.